# Can't build Garmin Connect IQ Samples getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: macos, connect, garmin

I'm trying to get the Garmin Connect IQ to work on OSX with no success. I have tried to build even the samples but keep getting a 'java.lang.NullPointerException' error.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ javac -version
java 1.8.0_74
$ monkeyc -v
Connect IQ compiler version 1.2.9
$ cd ~/Garmin/connectiq-sdk-mac-1.2.9/samples/Sensor
$ monkeyc -o Sensor.prg -m manifest.xml 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.garmin.monkeybrains.compiler.Compiler.assemble(Compiler.java:671)
    at com.garmin.monkeybrains.Monkeybrains.runCompiler(Monkeybrains.java:759)
    at com.garmin.monkeybrains.Monkeybrains.compileApplication(Monkeybrains.java:557)
    at com.garmin.monkeybrains.Monkeybrains.main(Monkeybrains.java:1046)
ERROR:unknown:0: null
WARNING: The app name should reference a string resource using @Strings.AppName
WARNING: The launcher icon should reference a bitmap resource using @Drawables.LauncherIcon
```

I'm guessing it's something simple/fundamental!

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

1. monkeyc does not know which source & resource files you would like to compile.
2. monkeyc crashes when the value of -o parameter is not an absolute path. It still happens for 2.1.0 SDK.

As a workaround please provide an absolute path for -o parameter and don't forget about the missing source files:

```
cd ~/Garmin/connectiq-sdk-mac-1.2.9/samples/Sensor
monkeyc -o ~/Garmin/connectiq-sdk-mac-1.2.9/samples/Sensor/app.prg -m manifest.xml -z resources/bitmaps.xml:resources/strings.xml:resources/resources.xml source/Graph.mc source/Sensor.mc
```